# Loading content on tabpane with content already set

Tags: javafx, fxml

I would like to know if it is possible to keep content of tabpane while loading new content. 
By the way I am using fxml.

**FXML**

```
<content>
    <Rectangle fx:id="borderBottom"  x="0" y="500" width="500" />
    <!-- When I load the file this rectangles disappears. -->
    <fx:include source="someOtherFxml.fxml"/>
</content>
```

I want to know how to keep the rectangle on the tabpane and still be able to load the file. Right now when I load the fxml file the rectangle disappears.

**Controller**

```
package newasa;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;


public class AppseController implements Initializable {


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

Comment: @anyone Sorry about my spacing in my code but stack would not let me summit otherwise.

Comment: Add the newly loaded fxml into content, not set directly. I.e. not as: `tabpane.setContent(newfxml);` but as `tabpane.setContent(new VBox(rectangle, newfxml) );`. Also show how are you loading new fxml and setting it into content.

Comment: @UlukBiy do I put your code in the controller?

Comment: Yes but if could provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i could say exactly to where.

Comment: @UlukBiy In my controller  do I make my own methods? I have not worked on controllers before?  I will edit the code tomorrow.

Comment: Yes the controller is there to add functionality to your app by adding new methods like in regular Java class.

Comment: @UlukBiy Ok I added my controller hope that helps.

Comment: @UlukBiy do you have an answer.

Comment: @UlukBiy thx bro for taking your time to answer. Did the answer you give work for you because I am unable to be at a pc right now and I want to know. Also the application I am working is very big and I want to know if I can hire you to help me(us) finish it on time. Yes you will be joining a company.  Contact me: doctype85@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the tab content with some layout pane. Ex:

```
<content>
  <VBox>
    <children>
      <Rectangle fx:id="borderBottom"  x="0" y="500" width="500" />
      <fx:include source="someOtherFxml.fxml"/>
   </children>
  </VBox>
</content>
```